# multiple successes in Coq branching and backtracking?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I am having trouble understanding the concept of `multiple successes` in Coq's (8.5p1, ch9.2) branching and backtracking behavior. For example, from the documentation:

> Backtracking branching
>
> We can branch with the following structure:
>
> expr1 + expr2
>
> Tactics can be seen as having several successes. When a tactic fails
>   it asks for more successes of the prior tactics. expr1 + expr2 has all
>   the successes of v1 followed by all the successes of v2.

What I don't understand, is why do we need multiple successes in the first place? Isn't one success good enough to finish a proof?

Also from the documentation, it seems that there are less costly branching rules that are somehow "biased", including

```
first [ expr1 | ::: | exprn ]
```

and

```
expr1 || expr2
```

Why do we need the more costly option `+` and not always use the latter, more efficient tacticals?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are sometimes trying to discharge a goal but further subgoals might lead to a solution you thought would work to be rejected. If you accumulate all the successes then you can backtrack to wherever you made a wrong choice and explore another branch of the search tree.

Here is a silly example. let's say I want to prove this goal:

```
Goal exists m, m = 1.
```

Now, it's a fairly simple goal so I could do it manually but let's not. Let's write a tactic that, when confronted with an `exists`, tries all the possible natural numbers. If I write:

```
Ltac existNatFrom n :=
  exists n || existNatFrom (S n).

Ltac existNat := existNatFrom O.
```

then as soon as I have run `existNat`, the system commits to the first successful choice. In particular this means that despite the recursive definition of `existNatFrom`, when calling `existNat` I'll always get `O` and only `O`.

The goal cannot be solved:

```
Goal exists m, m = 1.
  Fail (existNat; reflexivity).
Abort.
```

On the other hand, if I use `(+)` instead of `(||)`, I'll go through all possible natural numbers (in a lazy manner, by using backtracking). So writing:

```
Ltac existNatFrom' n :=
  exists n + existNatFrom' (S n).

Ltac existNat' := existNatFrom' O.
```

means that I can now prove the goal:

```
Goal exists m, m = 1.
  existNat'; reflexivity.
Qed.
```